# How to add a value after a given value in parts of a list, returning a new list?

Tags: list, mapping

I have the following structure:

```
'((a (1 2 3 4))
  (b (1 2))
  (c (1 3 4 5))
```

I want to return a new list that's similar, but that has a `7` inserted after each `2`:

```
'((a (1 2 7 3 4))
  (b (1 2 7))
  (c (1 3 4 5))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You do _not_ want to _mutate_ a **quoted** list. Also, `mapcar` is non-destructive, i.e., it does _not_ mutate its arguments.

Comment: @sds maybe I was unable to explain myself better, due to my lack of Lisp expertise I guess, but I'm okay if the result is a new list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a nested [`mapcar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/mapcar.html) and [`mapcan`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html):

```
(mapcar
 (lambda (l)
   (list (car l)
         (mapcan
          (lambda (x)
            (if (= x 2)
                (list x 7)
              (list x)))
          (cadr l))))
 '((a (1 2 3 4))
   (b (1 2))
   (c (1 3 4 5))))
==> ((a (1 2 7 3 4)) (b (1 2 7)) (c (1 3 4 5)))
```